# How to test URL args of POST request?

Tags: python, django, testing, django-rest-framework

I have a POST view, which also get GET argument `?company=` from URL. How to test it using Django Rest Framework test tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't know, that it is possible to change GET and POST properties:

```
request = APIRequestFactory().post('', data={}, format='json')
request.GET = {'company': 1}
```